# Meta meta tag synonym: [about-page] [stackexchange-tour]

Tags: support, meta, synonym-request

I believe these two tags on this very Meta should be considered synonyms:

- [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour) (24 questions, more descriptive name)
- [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) (63 questions, legacy name, has synonym [tour](/questions/tagged/tour))

Of all of these names, [tour](/questions/tagged/tour) seems like the best one to be primary since it is short and complete.

Comment: I'd rather have [stackexchange-tour] because the tour is *usually* used by people new to the SE model, hence the 'stackexchange' part of the tour...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I was thinking about discoverability, but of course that doesn't matter given the existence of synonyms. Fair enough.